# invalid json in php jsonlint

Tags: php, json

i have script like this :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/?weather=USA");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$row = json_decode($result, TRUE);
echo $row['teston'];
?>
```

and json look like this :

```
{
    "test": ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    "teston": "teston2",
    "debug": {}
} {
    "test": ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    "teston": "teston2",
    "debug": {}
}
```

i get json data in other site,and jsonlint have notice is json is invalid

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
...n2", "debug": {}} {  "test": ["test1",
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

What must i do so my script work?

EDIT : After i add `var_dump($result);` it output :

```
string(1204) "{
    "test": ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    "teston": "teston2",
    "debug": {}
} {
    "test": ["test1", "test2", "test3"],
    "teston": "teston2",
    "debug": {}
}"
```

I'm convert that json from XML with this code :

```
<?php
$result = $this->rawResponse;
$config = Array(
    'input-xml' => 1,
);
$repairitfirst = tidy_repair_string($result, $config);
$willbearray = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($repairitfirst));
$jsonfromxml = $willbearray;
?>
```

is something wrong with my php convert code?
in my script contain loops like this :

```
<?php
foreach($this->params as $key=>$val)
{
  $this->rawRequest .= "&$key=$val";
}
?>
```

How to $this->params as $key=>$val without loops? is it possible?

Comment: do a `var_dump($result);` and update your question with the output

Comment: already edited,thanks

Comment: the service is returning malformed `json`, is it a public api or it's under your control?

Comment: The JSON objects are not linked properly. There should be a "," after one object ends. This should be handled at the server side where the curl request is initiated.

Comment: @AlexAndrei : it's public api

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq : So any solution to change it so it will be valid?

Comment: Every object except the last should be appended with "," before it is returned.

Comment: Why do you have 2 json objects with the same data? Are you doing this in a loop?

Comment: @Sean: Server has send it,not me

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact the server then and tell them that they are sending invalid json.

Comment: what is the public api, so we can test also

Comment: i'm use public api that using XML and i convert it.Edited Question

Comment: So is your json output from your `php convert code` or is the json output from the public api? Is your `php convert code` in a loop, or called multiple times?

Comment: edited,please read again